# Using CLR to get value from registry

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

Is there a way to get a value from the registry using a CLR procedure that doesnt involve having to registry Microsoft.Win32 as an assembly in SQL Server?

I am looking to get the DigitalProductId (I will need to decode it to a string) from the registry within a CLR proc and return it to SQL.

Supported Namespaces

```
CustomMarshalers
Microsoft.VisualBasic
Microsoft.VisualC
mscorlib
System
System.Configuration
System.Data
System.Data.OracleClient
System.Data.SqlXml
System.Deployment
System.Security
System.Transactions
System.Web.Services
System.Xml
System.Core.dll
System.Xml.Linq.dll
```

Could I use a method in mscorlib  for this?

**Edit:**  Am I missing something here? Microsoft.Win32 appears to be usable in the CLR?
Edit: Yes, I was missing something. It will need to be set as an UNSAFE assembly and then signed etc before I can use Microsoft.WIn32.

Comment: Just FYI: You don't need to set your Assembly to `UNSAFE` to _use_ `Microsoft.Win32`, you only need `UNSAFE` if you are accessing certain code inside of that class and/or system resources that require it. There is probably code in the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace that will run in `SAFE` Assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "supported namespaces" do you mean assemblies? mscorlib contains the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace, which exposes the `Registry` type.

Answer (score 0):

you might try using Win32 api directly with RegOpenKeyEx (advapi32)
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/RegOpenKeyEx.html

Comment: The problem is using external or non supported libraries within a CLR. I'd have the same issue of having to register the dll as an assembly in SQL. I would like to do this using the supported namespaces only if possible.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It is definitely possible as the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace is contained in `mscorlib.dll` which is supported. And I have use the `RegistryKey` class myself without having to register any other DLLs into SQL Server.